# automata theorem: existance of a DFA

Tags: finite-automata, automata, formal-languages

I need to prove that for every k, there's a DFA M with k+2 states, so in every automat M' who accepts the language reverse(L(M)) there are at least 2^k states.

Help would be really appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the alphabet set contains at least two elements, let it be `{0,1}`.

Next, let `M` be the automata accepting the language `L` defined as:

> All the strings which k-th position is 1

defined as:

> M = {Q,{0,1},q<sub>0</sub>,{q<sub>k+1</sub>},δ}, where
>
> Q={q<sub>0</sub>,q<sub>1</sub>,...,q<sub>k</sub>,q<sub>F</sub>}
>
> δ(q<sub>i</sub>,a) = q<sub>i+1</sub>, for a in {0,1} and i=0,1,...,k-2
>
> δ(q<sub>k-1</sub>,0) = q<sub>F</sub>,
>
> δ(q<sub>k-1</sub>,1) = q<sub>k</sub>,
>
> δ(q<sub>F</sub>,a) = q<sub>F</sub>, for a in {0,1}

Note that `M` has exactly `k+2` states, and that it accepts the language `L`.

Now, note that the language `reverse(L(M))` can be translated as:

> All the strings which k-th position *from the end* is 1

To recognize that language, note that we need to remember the last k symbols, because we don't know when the string will end. We know that there are at least 2<sup>k</sup> possible strings of length k (since the alphabet size is at least 2).

So using a DFA, we need at least 2<sup>k</sup> states, each to represent one possible string of length k. <sub>▢</sub>

#### Author's note:

The idea of this proof is to find a language which is "easy" to be recognized in normal way, but "difficult" when is read backward. Through **experience**, I remember that fixing the k-th position from the *beginning* is "easy", while k-th position from the *end* is "difficult", hence my answer.